# Сверстать прозрачную стрелку

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, css3

Суть в том, что стрелка находится на фоне, но она должна быть полупрозрачной, как это можно реализовать?

http://dropi.ru/a/nPv

Comment: Используйте SVG

Answer (score 2):

1. Нарисовать полупрозрачным градиентом и сохранить в png, потому что иначе стрелка будет существовать отдельно от меню сверху
2. Применить css-свойство [opacity](http://htmlbook.ru/css/opacity).

Comment: Это ясно, но стрелка должка как бы вырезать контент, белый фон

Comment: @Fangog, я ничего не понял